# C# nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

What is wrong with my syntax? I want to be able to get the value "Genesis" with this `info["Gen"]["name"]`

```
    public var info = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> {
    {"Gen", new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"name", "Genesis"},
    {"chapters", "50"},
    {"before", ""},
    {"after", "Exod"}
    }},
    {"Exod", new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"name", "Exodus"},
    {"chapters", "40"},
    {"before", "Gen"},
    {"after", "Lev"}
    }}};
```

Comment: And what compiler error do you get?

Comment: Do you get a compile error at the word `var` ..?

Comment: Aside from the actual cause of the error, why are you using a `Dictionary<string, string>` as the value anyway, when it appears you really want a simple `Chapter` class?

Comment: Yeah I think the issue is "var" because it is directly in a class and not used in a method. What should I use instead?

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet, I think that creating a class would be the correct route and if he wanted a Collection then he could create a List<T> of the Class itself.

Comment: @MethodMan Just popping in to say I'm jealous of your username for the reference and the pun

Comment: LOL @CaptainMarvel thanks man

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot define a class field using `var`.

Change `var` to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> info =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        {
            "Gen",
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"name", "Genesis"},
                {"chapters", "50"},
                {"before", ""},
                {"after", "Exod"}
            }
        },
        {
            "Exod",
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"name", "Exodus"},
                {"chapters", "40"},
                {"before", "Gen"},
                {"after", "Lev"}
            }
        }
    };
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables) for more information about `var` keyword and its usage.

In C# 9, with the introduction of [target-typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new), you can rewrite the field definition as:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> info = new()
{
    {
        "Gen",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"name", "Genesis"},
            {"chapters", "50"},
            {"before", ""},
            {"after", "Exod"}
        }
    },
    {
        "Exod",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"name", "Exodus"},
            {"chapters", "40"},
            {"before", "Gen"},
            {"after", "Lev"}
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

From *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)*;

> - var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized
>     in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or
>     to a method group or an anonymous function.
> - **var cannot be used on fields at class scope.**
> - Variables declared by using var cannot be used in the initialization
>     expression.

Just change your `var` to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. Like;

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> info =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>{}
```