# How can i make nested dictionaries in c#

Tags: python, c#, .net, dictionary, nested

I do have a python code that has nested dictionaries. The python code is as follows:

```
T_DICT = {
       "ABC_Table":
           {
             "table": "ABC",
             "schema": "XYZ",
             "columns": 
                 { 
                   'Id': {"type": 'bigint', "name": "[ID]", 'IsIden': True, 'IsNull': False},
                   'T_ID': {"type": 'bigint', "name": "Tsa", 'IsIden': False, 'IsNull': False},
                 }
           }
         }
```

I wanted to do the same thing in C#. Please can anyone help me with how to do the same thing in C#?

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? Telling us what you want to happen is not a problem statement. We're not here to make it happen for you. If you haven't tried anything then you haven't encountered an actual iss yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501202/c-sharp-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2):

```
T_DICT = { 
    "ABC_Table": { 
        "table": "ABC", 
        "schema": "XYZ", 
        "columns": { 
            'Id': {
                "type": 'bigint', 
                "name": "[ID]", 
                'IsIden': True, 
                'IsNull': False
            }, 
            'T_ID': {
                "type": 'bigint', 
                "name": "Tsa", 
                'IsIden': False, 
                'IsNull': False
            }, 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I think you forgot a `"` after `"[ID]`.

---

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

This type is similar to what you need, but won't allow you to put the keys "table" and "schema".

---

So, for what you really need... [C#: Using a generic dictionary <key, object> to hold settings of mixed type and return correct value and typecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754229/c-using-a-generic-dictionary-key-object-to-hold-settings-of-mixed-type-and)

I don't think there's a clean solution for this.